Bar chart is not displaying correctly in flutter
I am using the fl_chart library (v0.70).
I am wanting to create a bar chart like the one shown here on number 5. The source code can be seen here.
I have copied this code and amended it so it utilises my data source. The only change I made is essentially the mainItems map, there are no multiple groups of bar chart data, i'm only displaying one. This is my bar chart.
When populating the datasource, it appears like this:

It seems that:

The bar chart is not contained within its box. The bar chart shoots to the height of the current window it seems.
There are no labels present. I've kept the labels from the github example so i was expecting to see some labels but unfortunately that wasn't the case.
I did directly copy the example into my code before i made any alterations to the code and even then the labels did not appear (although the bar charts were contained and did not overshoot).

When I just copy the example directly from the github example (although replacing any usages of AppColors with just Colors and removing any usages of AppUtils()) this is how it looks like:

This is my code:
class BarChartSample5 extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Expenditure> expenditures;
  bool displayMonthly;
  DateTime date;
  bool displayAverage;
  BarChartSample5(
      {super.key,
      required this.expenditures,
      required this.displayMonthly,
      required this.date,
      required this.displayAverage});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => BarChartSample5State();
}

class BarChartSample5State extends State<BarChartSample5> {
  static const double barWidth = 22;
  static const shadowOpacity = 0.2;
  int touchedIndex = -1;

  Map<int, double> expendituresAcrossTheYear = <int, double>{
    //first element is the variable income, second is the fixed income, third is the variable expense, fourth is the fixed expense
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget bottomTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10);
    String text;
    switch (value.toInt()) {
      case 0:
        text = 'Mon';
        break;
      case 1:
        text = 'Tue';
        break;
      case 2:
        text = 'Wed';
        break;
      case 3:
        text = 'Thu';
        break;
      case 4:
        text = 'Fri';
        break;
      case 5:
        text = 'Sat';
        break;
      case 6:
        text = 'Sun';
        break;
      default:
        text = '';
        break;
    }
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      child: Text(text, style: style),
    );
  }

  Widget topTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10);
    String text;
    switch (value.toInt()) {
      case 0:
        text = 'Mon';
        break;
      case 1:
        text = 'Tue';
        break;
      case 2:
        text = 'Wed';
        break;
      case 3:
        text = 'Thu';
        break;
      case 4:
        text = 'Fri';
        break;
      case 5:
        text = 'Sat';
        break;
      case 6:
        text = 'Sun';
        break;
      default:
        return Container();
    }
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      child: Text(text, style: style),
    );
  }

  Widget leftTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10);
    String text;
    if (value == 0) {
      text = '0';
    } else {
      text = '${value.toInt()}0k';
    }
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      space: 4,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: style,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget rightTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10);
    String text;
    if (value == 0) {
      text = '0';
    } else {
      text = '${value.toInt()}0k';
    }
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      space: 0,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: style,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  BarChartGroupData generateGroup(int x, double value1) {
    final isTop = value1 > 0;
    final sum = value1;
    final isTouched = touchedIndex == x;
    return BarChartGroupData(
      x: x,
      groupVertically: true,
      showingTooltipIndicators: isTouched ? [0] : [],
      barRods: [
        BarChartRodData(
          toY: sum,
          width: barWidth,
          borderRadius: isTop
              ? const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(6),
                )
              : const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
                ),
          rodStackItems: [
            BarChartRodStackItem(
              0,
              value1,
              Colors.green,
              BorderSide(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: isTouched ? 2 : 0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        BarChartRodData(
          toY: -sum,
          width: barWidth,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: isTop
              ? const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
                )
              : const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(6),
                ),
          rodStackItems: [],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  bool isShadowBar(int rodIndex) => rodIndex == 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    populateBarChartData();
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 0.8,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
        child: BarChart(
          BarChartData(
            alignment: BarChartAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            maxY: 20,
            minY: -20,
            groupsSpace: 12,
            barTouchData: BarTouchData(
              handleBuiltInTouches: false,
              touchCallback: (FlTouchEvent event, barTouchResponse) {
                if (!event.isInterestedForInteractions ||
                    barTouchResponse == null ||
                    barTouchResponse.spot == null) {
                  setState(() {
                    touchedIndex = -1;
                  });
                  return;
                }
                final rodIndex = barTouchResponse.spot!.touchedRodDataIndex;
                if (isShadowBar(rodIndex)) {
                  setState(() {
                    touchedIndex = -1;
                  });
                  return;
                }
                setState(() {
                  touchedIndex = barTouchResponse.spot!.touchedBarGroupIndex;
                });
              },
            ),
            titlesData: FlTitlesData(
              show: true,
              topTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  reservedSize: 32,
                  getTitlesWidget: topTitles,
                ),
              ),
              bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  reservedSize: 32,
                  getTitlesWidget: bottomTitles,
                ),
              ),
              leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  getTitlesWidget: leftTitles,
                  interval: 5,
                  reservedSize: 42,
                ),
              ),
              rightTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  getTitlesWidget: rightTitles,
                  interval: 5,
                  reservedSize: 42,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            gridData: FlGridData(
              show: true,
              checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) => value % 5 == 0,
              getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
                if (value == 0) {
                  return FlLine(
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                  );
                }
                return FlLine(
                  strokeWidth: 0.8,
                );
              },
            ),
            borderData: FlBorderData(
              show: false,
            ),
            barGroups: expendituresAcrossTheYear.entries
                .map(
                  (e) => generateGroup(e.key, e.value),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void populateBarChartData() {
    getTrueValueOfExpenditures(
        DateTime(widget.date.year, 1, 1),
        DateTime(widget.date.year, 12, 31),
        widget.expenditures); //This will be for yearly data
  }

  void getTrueValueOfExpenditures(
      DateTime from, DateTime to, List<Expenditure> expenditures) {
    expendituresAcrossTheYear.clear();
    //... performs calculations and directly updates the expendituresAcrossTheYear map vaiable (not using setState();)
  }
}

Thank you for your time!

Turns out there is a parameter called maxX and maxY in the BarChartData widget. As for the label..... the font colour was the same color as the background color (facepalm).
